# Issues while using .loc with a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
    raw=pd.read_csv('raw_6_12_8_30.csv')
    raw2=raw.loc[raw['spices'].isnull()==False]  # code for deleting 10 values #

    b=[]

    for i in range(len(raw2)):
        if raw2['Status'][i]==0:            # codes didn't run perfectly#
            print(i)
```

But when I use this code without line 2, it works fine.

```
    raw=pd.read_csv('raw_6_12_8_30.csv')
    b=[]

    for i in range(len(raw)):
        if raw['Status'][i]==0:            
            print(i)
```

I checked there is no errors in this raw2['Status] and raw['Status']

But whenever I use `pandas.loc` ,there is an error.

I bet that line 2 makes an error but I don't know why?

error images here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJiB2.png)

key errors 11  # what is it #

Comment: In your own words: when you do `for i in range(len(raw))`, what values will `i` have? Now, you are using the values like so: `raw['Status'][i]`. Does that make sense? How many things are in `raw`? How many things are in `raw['Status']`? Do you expect those answers to be the same? Why?

Answer (score 1):

there are 3 ways to get values from dataframe by indexing.

1. **loc** gets rows (or columns) with particular labels from the index.
2. **iloc** gets rows (or columns) at particular positions in the index (so it only takes integers).
3. **ix** usually tries to behave like loc but falls back to behaving like iloc if a label is not present in the index.

if you want to take values by indexing you can use iloc. Like in the code below

```
raw=pd.read_csv('raw_6_12_8_30.csv')
b=[]

for i in range(len(raw)):
    if raw['Status'].iloc[i]==0:            
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try with :

```
for i in range(0,len(raw)-1):
```

i guess key error 11 occur because of index range. the key 11 may be out of range.

Comment: no... it doesn't work. to solve the question i have to make new csv file like raw2.to_csv('raw3.csv) and i recall the new table raw3= pd.read_csv('raw3.csv') and then it works. i don't know why

Comment: hmm, interesting. can you share the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to drop all rows where `spices` is `null`?

```
raw.dropna(subset="spices", inplace=True)
```

To print where the status is 0:

```
raw_subset = raw[raw["Status"]==0]
print(raw_subset)

# To get the specific indices
print(raw_subset.index)
```